# restconf: what is the correct api call for configuring a BGP peer

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to bring up a BGP session (linkstate family, if it matters).
Following this guide https://github.com/opendaylight/docs/blob/master/docs/user-guide/bgpcep-guide/bgp/bgp-user-guide-linkstate-family.rst

When I am making a request using
as URL `/restconf/config/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance/global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols`
and as body

```
<protocol xmlns="http://openconfig.net/yang/network-instance">
    <name>nl-ams02c-ispbgp01</name>
    <identifier xmlns:x="http://openconfig.net/yang/policy-types">x:BGP</identifier>
    <bgp xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions">
        <global>
            <config>
                <router-id>10.20.14.1</router-id>
                <as>xxx</as>
            </config>
            <afi-safis>
                <afi-safi>
                    <afi-safi-name>LINKSTATE</afi-safi-name>
                </afi-safi>
            </afi-safis>
        </global>
    </bgp>
</protocol>
```

It seems that the family was added to the BGP speaker, I am checking this with

```
In [5]: url = "/restconf/operational/bgp-rib:bgp-rib"

In [6]: requests.get('http://{}:{}{}'.format(odl['api']['ipaddr'],odl['api']['port'],url), auth=auth).json()
Out[6]: 
{'bgp-rib': {'rib': [{'id': 'nl-ams02c-ispbgp01',
    'loc-rib': {'tables': [{'afi': 'bgp-linkstate:linkstate-address-family',
       'safi': 'bgp-linkstate:linkstate-subsequent-address-family',
       'bgp-linkstate:linkstate-routes': {},
       'attributes': {'uptodate': True}}, ...
```

**Question #1**
I do not know though how to check and where should I expect to see the local IP address (10.20.14.1 in the above example) that is used for this BGP session. What would be the HTTP GET request for that ?

Next, when I am trying to configure the BGP peer using
as URL `/restconf/config/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances/network-instance/global-bgp/openconfig-network-instance:protocols/protocol/openconfig-policy-types:BGP/nl-ams02c-ispbgp01/bgp/neighbors`
and as body

```
<neighbor xmlns="urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions">
    <neighbor-address>10.20.14.0</neighbor-address>
    <afi-safis>
        <afi-safi>
            <afi-safi-name>LINKSTATE</afi-safi-name>
        </afi-safi>
    </afi-safis>
</neighbor>
```

I get the following error:

```
{'errors': {'error': [{'error-type': 'protocol',
    'error-tag': 'malformed-message',
    'error-message': 'Error parsing input: Child "protocol" was not found in parent schema node "(urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions?revision=2017-12-07)neighbors"',
    'error-info': 'Child "protocol" was not found in parent schema node "(urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:bgp:openconfig-extensions?revision=2017-12-07)neighbors"'}]}}
```

**Question #2** 
Could you please help me and advise on the correct HTTP call to configure a BGP peer ?

PS. I am running OpenDaylight Oxygen-SR2

UPDATE: I found out that RESTCONF API Explorer is of help, still browsing through it..

Answer (score 0):

taking advantage of https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Restconf_API_Explorer

the answer to question #1 is: `http://127.0.0.1:8181/restconf/config/openconfig-network-instance:network-instances`

question #2 remains un-answered :)